# Validate a String date with yyyy-MM-dd format in WSO2

Tags: javascript, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2 MI 1.2.0. I need to validate a date that comes as a String with yyyy-MM-dd format.
Need to consider the major validations of date and avoid the below kind of invalid dates.

- 2021-02-29
- 2021-03-32
- 2021-14-03
- 2021-1r-09
- 2020-10-09t

I tried to use script mediator as mention in below. But it's passing **invalid date** when trying to invoke **new Date()** function.

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[var myDate = mc.getProperty("myDate");
     var regEx = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;
     var isMyDateValid = 'false';
      if(isValidDate(myDate)) {
            isMyDateValid = 'true';
    }
            
    function isValidDate(dateString) {
        var log = mc.getServiceLog();        
        log.info("Logging inside Script Mediator"+dateString);
          var regEx = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;
          if(!dateString.match(regEx)) {
            return false;
          }
          var d = new Date(dateString);
          log.info("Logging inside Script Mediator d : "+d);
          var dNum = d.getTime();
          if(!dNum && dNum !== 0){
            return false;
          }
          return d.toISOString().slice(0,10) === dateString;
        }

    mc.setProperty("isMyDateValid", isMyDateValid);]]></script>
```

What can be the best ways to overcome this? Or any other alternative suggestions are also welcome.
Thank You in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with WSO2 Script Mediator, is in that it does not run the script directly in the selected language, but wraps itself into Java and then tries to run. And that's why sometimes the JavaScript is not work as expected. It's better to write there code in Java - yes, you can do that. For your validating problem you can use, something like below:

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[
var myDate = mc.getProperty("myDate");
try {
  //Java 8 uses 'uuuu' for year, not 'yyyy'. In Java 8, ‘yyyy’ means “year of era” (BC or AD).
  var dateFormat = "uuuu-MM-dd";
  var dtf = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat);
  java.time.LocalDate.parse(myDate, dtf.withResolverStyle(java.time.format.ResolverStyle.STRICT));
  mc.setProperty("isMyDateValid", true);
} catch (error) {
  mc.setProperty("isMyDateValid", false);
}      
]]></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! for the well-descriptive answer. This works perfectly. Didn't know that we can use java code inside script mediator. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateDate(str) {
  const date = new Date(str)
  const isValid = !isNaN(date.getTime())
  return isValid && date.toISOString().slice(0, 10) === str
}

function main() {
  console.log(validateDate('2021-02-29'))
  console.log(validateDate('2021-03-32'))
  console.log(validateDate('2021-14-03'))
  console.log(validateDate('2021-1r-09'))
  console.log(validateDate('2020-10-09t'))
  console.log(validateDate('2020-02-29'))
}
main()
```

outputs:

```
false
false
false
false
false
true
```

Comment: Not working inside wso2 script mediator. date is printed as 'Invalid Date'.

Comment: Provide the code or the date you check pls

Comment: It was a problem with the Script mediator as mentioned by @tmoasz. Anyway, thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var invalidDates = `2021-02-29
2021-03-32
2021-14-03
2021-1r-09
2020-10-09t`.split('\n');

var validDates = `2020-02-29
2021-03-31
2021-02-03
2021-11-09
2020-10-09`.split('\n');

function isValidDate(dateString) {
  var d = new Date(dateString);
  if(isFinite(d.getTime())) {
    const [ year, month, date ] = dateString.split("-");
    return d.getFullYear() == +year && (d.getMonth() + 1) == +month && d.getDate() == +date;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(invalidDates.map(isValidDate));
console.log(validDates.map(isValidDate));
```

Comment: Not working inside wso2 script mediator. d is printed as 'Invalid Date'.

Comment: Is it printing invalid date even for valid dates?

Comment: Yes, for any of the String it's printing 'Invalid Date'

Comment: Can you check what is the value coming in `myDate` variable

Comment: It's printed correctly. Checked with valid and invalid (ex/ 2021-06-24, 2021-06-32) . Also, it seems the script mediator even not supported the isFinite() method.

Comment: Okay, pease check by replacing `isFinite(...)` with `Number.isFinite(...)`

Comment: It was a problem with the Script mediator as mentioned by @tmoasz. Anyway, thanks for the support.